# Generate deformation fields from Jacobian determinant

Tags: python, image-processing, vector

I want to shrink a region in a 3D image by generating deformation fields. I want to be able to set a region that I have selected to have some Jacobian determinant (lets say 0.7). I want to then generate deformation vectors that could produce such a shrinkage so that the Jacobian determinants are roughly 0.7.

The strategy I have tried is as follows (breifly)

Create an ideal Jacobain volume

- Set values of an internal cube within the volume to 0.7 (shrinkage)
- Set surrounding values to 1.0 (no shrinkage)

Create a 3D volume of vectors same size as the image, with all vectors set to (0,0,0)

I have then implemented a genetic algorithm in Python using deap. 
During each iteration, the vectors have a small chance of being altered. The resulting deformation field is used to generate a Jacobian determinant at each position, which is compared with the ideal Jacobian volume to select the fittest for the next round of breeeding and mutating.

After several thousand iterations I was able to generate fairly good approximation of the ideal Jacobian volume when using a test cube data. When I try it on real data from a 
real 3D image it does not work.

Can anyone suggest a better approach to generate deformation fields to shrink a region of an image.

Comment: How would you quantify 'better'? In what way did it not work?

Comment: It did not work in that the resulting jacobians were not anywhere like the ideal that I was comparing against. A plot of the sum of squared difference intensites showed it plateaued out after around 100 iterations. I was wondering if there was an approach other than GA that might be more appropriate